# Changing state of navigation in AngularJS UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a relatively simple UI-Router set up, except that the navigation that changes states is itself a ui-view.

**Main HTML:**

```
<header class="container__header">
    <nav class="container__header__tabs" ui-view="nav"></nav>
</header>
```

**Nav HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="nav-link active"><a ui-sref="/">all funds</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a ui-sref=".something">something</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that the `.something` link can't change state views on click.

**My AngularJS config:**

```
.state('home.something', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'nav': {templateUrl: 'templates/navs/explorer-nav.html'},
            'main': {templateUrl: 'templates/fund explorer/fund_explorer_all.html'}
        }       
});
```

This doesn't change the view templates (though the URL does change). Any ideas?

Comment: Don't remember this off the top of my head, but shouldn't you be navigating to `home.something`?

Comment: The URL does seem to change correctly, it's just the templates

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `<li class="nav-link"><a ui-sref=".something">something</a></li>`

Here you have used state as `.something` which is not defined in `config`.

Change it to

`<li class="nav-link"><a ui-sref="home.something">something</a></li>`

It should be `home.something` which means state should be same as defined in config.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router (Check - Nested States & Views)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. The config **only** uses `home.something` in this question

Comment: Oh oh sorry. No that doesn't help either

Comment: Try after removing `'main': {templateUrl: 'templates/fund explorer/fund_explorer_all.html'}` from `config` and make sure that `templateUrl` path for `nav` view is proper...

Comment: Ok..Can you add plunkr example